# Show jScrollPane in Qtip

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, lightbox, tooltip, jscrollpane

I use `Jscrollpane` for my new project. which works great on the page.

The page works fine but when it is called inside the qtip, the customized
bar disappears.

See the customized scroll bar [81.171.199.24/qtip/scrollpanel.html](http://81.171.199.24/qtip/scrollpanel.html)

See qtip example (click snowy Owl link): [81.171.199.24/qtip/index.html](http://81.171.199.24/qtip/index.html)

The developer from qtip suggest I should include the scroll script on your
qTip page, and call the `jScrollPanel` method within the `onRender` callback of
your tooltip otherwise won't work since it's simply retrieving the HTML
from the page, not parsing the JS on it too.

So I tried to put the code in the `onRender` function like

```
onRender: function(){
   $Q('#pop-panel').jScrollPane({scrollbarWidth:15,scrollbarMargin:0});
}
```

I also tried to use

```
onRender: function(){
   this.elements.content.jScrollPane({scrollbarWidth:15, scrollbarMargin:0});
}
```

But I still can't get any luck.

The reason I think is not working are:

1. I think the two script got conflict,which means I need to use jquery noconflict inside the onRender function.
2. the scrollbar div is in the scrollpanel.html not on the index.html.
   If I use `this.elements.content.jScrollPane....` , should this only affect the element inside "`#report_main_content a[rel]`".

Please give some suggestions, thank you so much for the help.

tanya

Answer (score 1):

```
api: {
    onRender: function(){
        alert("here");
    }
}
```

Comment: `api` is an option to the `qtip` call. `$(..).qtip({ content: 'My text content in tooltip', api: { onRender: function(){ alert('onRender'); } } });`